# Why don't I see registered Mbean in jconsole?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have read following article to start learn `JMX`:

http://www.journaldev.com/1352/what-is-jmx-mbean-jconsole-tutorial

But I faced with issues.
java code:

MBean interface:

```
package com.journaldev.jmx;

public interface SystemConfigMBean {

    public void setThreadCount(int noOfThreads);
    public int getThreadCount();

    public void setSchemaName(String schemaName);
    public String getSchemaName();

    public String doConfig();
}
```

implementation:

```
public class SystemConfig implements SystemConfigMBean {

    private int threadCount;
    private String schemaName;

    public SystemConfig(int numThreads, String schema){
        this.threadCount=numThreads;
        this.schemaName=schema;
    }


    @Override
    public String doConfig(){
        return "No of Threads="+this.threadCount+" and DB Schema Name="+this.schemaName;
    }

   //get and set methods

}
```

main method:

```
public class SystemConfigManagement {
    private static final int DEFAULT_NO_THREADS=10;
    private static final String DEFAULT_SCHEMA="default";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedObjectNameException, InterruptedException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException, MBeanRegistrationException, NotCompliantMBeanException {
        //Get the MBean server
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        //register the MBean
        SystemConfig mBean = new SystemConfig(DEFAULT_NO_THREADS, DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("com.journaldev.jmx:type=SystemConfig");
        mbs.registerMBean(mBean, name);
        do{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Thread Count="+mBean.getThreadCount()+":::Schema Name="+mBean.getSchemaName());
        }while(mBean.getThreadCount() !=0);

    }

}
```

After apllication launching in console I see expected result:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\freelance\JmxHelloWorld\out\production\JmxHelloWorld;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.journaldev.jmx.SystemConfigManagement 
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
Thread Count=10:::Schema Name=default
...
```

After I go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jconsole.exe`

and see following views

[image]
==>

[image]
==>

[image]

As you can see I don't see `com.journaldev.jmx` in tree in left part of screen.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are in the wrong process? I see you have a RemoteMavenServer and an AppMain Process. I'm assuming is your `AppMain` since your launching console shows `com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.journaldev.jmx.SystemConfigManagement`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is work after using com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain